# store index of matrix for minimum

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a 2d matrix `Ac(yr,j)`. 
I want it to compare each value of it with another 1D array and store the value of array for which absolute minimum is coming.

```
for yr=1:32,  
   for j=1:12,  
       for in=1.5:1:32.5,  
            actin=Ac(yr,j);  
            kar(in-0.5)=abs(in-actin);  
            dab(yr,j)=min(kar(kar>=0));              
       end         
   end  
end
```

I'm able to find the least positive value but not the value of `in` for which it is coming.

Comment: is there any reason why you're indexing as `1.5-0.5`,`2.5-0.5`,... instead of just `1,2,3...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call [max](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/max.html) as shown below in order to get the *index* instead of the *value*.

```
[~, dab(yr,j)] = min(kar(kar>=0));
```

In order to get rid of the nested loops you could try [arrayfun](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/arrayfun.html). Define the operation to be performed on every array element.

```
function [index] = myMinFunction(value, data)
    [val, index] = min(abs(data - value));
end
```

Execute the defined operations.

```
dab = arrayfun(@(x)myMinFunction(x, in), Ac)
```

Answer (score 0):

your code needs work, and I'm guessing `in` is the array you want to compare.

to start off, you can get rid of the third for loop and just do:

```
actin=Ac(yr,j);
kar = abs(in-actin)
```

the last expression puzzles me:
kar is always >=0 (from the abs function) so you don't need to check for it... worse, it will always return 1! so yo u will always get the first index of kar. Have you tried:

```
dab(yr,j)=min(kar);
```

?

Comment: Yeah . sorry its not properly written , You are right about unnecessary use of kar>0;